# MySQL update query takes too long

Tags: mysql

I'm currently testing my website and have come across a slow query and I am not able to fix it.

I have added an index on (`uid`, `deleted`) and still the update query takes some time.

Let me start with the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `uid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `notification` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `extras` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `deleted` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `notifications`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `uid` (`uid`,`deleted`);
```

This is the problem, when the table has more than a million rows, update queries take some time, see screenshot:

[image: Slow query time]

column `deleted` should always be 0 or 1.

Currently the table has 2.436.668 rows. (Just for testing purposes)

My question, is there a solution to speed this query up?

Comment: How often will you set all records to deleted=0, even when deleted is already 0?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! This is just a thought rather than an answer, but instead of using the "soft delete" approach, maybe you could use MariaDB's [temporal table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) capabilities? What is your Disk (HDD or SSD)? 3mins seems a **very** long time for 3m records? How big on average is the `extras` field? You don't mention your version of MySQL (you should **always** do so) - if it's 8, can you show the output of [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-analyze).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MySQL expert but from general relational database knowledge, write operations are generally much more expensive than reads. This is because of transaction overhead and ACID and maintaining indexes, etc..

That query forces the database engine to iterate over the whole table and set the `deleted` column to 0, even if already 0. You could modify your query to:

```
UPDATE notification SET deleted = 0 WHERE deleted = 1
```

That change might speed it up, or it might not; it depends on whether the engine will overwrite a 0 with another 0 or if it's optimized to skip that. But still, the query has to iterate over the whole table.

Another index, in combination with the where clause, could help. The first (or only) column in that index would have to be `deleted`. Then the query engine should be able to use an index scan or index seek instead of a full table scan and only iterate over only those rows `where deleted = 1`. If most rows are `deleted = 0`, that would really speed up the query. If most rows are `deleted = 1` then it won't be much help.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only time that you will ever need to perform that Update, then, well, you have already done it.  Yes, it takes time, as explained by another answer.  Live with it, and move on.

If you will need to do it again, read on...

You should never have to set a column on every row in a table.

Something like "deleted" usually happens only one row or a small number of rows at a time.

Rethink the processing.

**Plan B**

Since you mentioned "testing", maybe you will be doing this a lot?  See if the following will run faster:

```
CREATE TABLE b LIKE a;
INSERT INTO b
    (deleted, the-other-columns)
    SELECT 0, the-other-columns
        FROM a;
RENAME TABLE a TO old, b TO a;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Another approach is to reload the table from a dump (or a copy of the table) whenever you start a new test cycle.